# Secondary IP on Amazon EC2 unreachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ip

I've added a secondary private IP address to my EC2 instance and associated a new elastic IP with it.

My EC2 Instance now lists a single "Public IP" (the original public, elastic, IP) and 2 "Elastic IPs" (the original and the new one I've added)

All good I thought but I can't connect to the server using either HTTP or SSH at this new elastic IP.

I'm guessing that the single security group that's attached isn't being applied to the new elastic IP.

Looking for suggestions of how to debug this (logs?) or make sure the security group applies to both elastic IPs?

Could it be because the new elastic IP isn't listed as "Public IP" ? It's confusing having multiple definitions of what's "public". I've been assuming Elastic = Public

EDIT:
The server is running ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: Have you [Configured the Operating System on Your Instance to Recognize the Secondary Private IP Address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html#StepTwoConfigOS)?

Comment: It's ubuntu and I did check /etc/network/interfaces in which I found "source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg" which loads eth0 containng "iface eth0 inet dhcp". This made me think it was using DHCP to acquire IPs. You think I should edit this to a static declaration of both IPs?

Comment: I think you first need to switch to static IP, with your primary private IP, then add secondary static IP to the same interface. But I am not sure (and can't check right now) so it would probably be a good idea to make an image of the instance before you proceed.

Comment: Confirmed. I moved from DHCP to static and it appears to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04,just open the interface configuration file /etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg

Append the below lines with existing network config

```
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 172.30.1.123

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
address 172.30.1.124
```

Where 172.30.123 and 172.30.124 are your secondary private IPs, then restart the service.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart networking
```

Then, you can check that it's ok by ifconfig:

```
$ sudo ifconfig | fgrep -A2 eth0:1
```